# Subscriber logic

Tags: ros, python, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm stuck here now,

I have this common listener with a subscriber:

```
def listener():
    rospy.init_node('teleop_list', anonymous=True)

    rospy.Subscriber('key_vel', Twist, callback)

    # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    rospy.spin()
```

I want to know if there is a way to call the callback when no data is received (I already know the callback theory, when something happens the callback is triggered, and this is why I'm asking) or find a way to do something while the callback is not triggered

Ty

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281844/subscriber-logic/) by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can make a new thread in your Python program and have it call a function called callback that doesn't take inputs.

```
def callback():
    while True:
        crunchData()

# ... somewhere in the daemon startup code ...
t = threading.Thread(target=callback)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600737/how-to-use-daemon-that-has-a-while-loop?noredirect=1&lq=1

I copied over the sample example you might want to reference for what you want to do.

---

Originally posted by [kparikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28560/kparikh/) with karma: 53 on 2018-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on 2018-02-05**:
I can't imagine how can I connect what you are saing with the rospy.Subscriber.
I have this:

```
def callback(data):
    #do something with the data

def listener():
    rospy.Subscriber('key_vel', Twist, callback)
```

listener is the daemon startup code.

**Comment by [kparikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28560/kparikh/) on 2018-02-05**:
I'm telling you how to do something when the subscriber isn't triggered. Plus, you can't call callback(data) without providing data. You can either make another function which doesn't require the data or provide a predefined piece of data.

**Comment by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on 2018-02-05**:
yeah, after think a bit and read the whole stackoverflow post I think i get it. Thank you!

**Comment by [kparikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28560/kparikh/) on 2018-02-05**:
If you want to connect it, then try.

```
rospy.init_node('teleop_list', anonymous=True)
rospy.Subscriber('key_vel', Twist, callback)
def listener():
    #some logic to call a function or spin

t = threading.Thread(target=listener)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

**Comment by [kparikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28560/kparikh/) on 2018-02-05**:
Mark as answered and close if it works.

**Comment by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on 2018-02-05**:
the thread is called the same time with the Subscriber

```
def callback(data):
       #
def listener():
    #do smt

def main ():
    rospy.init_node('teleop_list', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('key_vel', Twist, callback)

    t = threading.Thread(target=listener)
```

**Comment by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on 2018-02-05**:
I got it, with some mods but thank you!!!

**Comment by [kparikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28560/kparikh/) on 2018-02-05**:
Yeah, not sure it would do what you want otherwise.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-06**:\

> Mark as answered and close if it works.

no need to close the question. Marking it as answered is enough.